# Getting selected value of a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem, selectedvalue, selectedindexchanged

```
public class ComboboxItem { 
            public string Text { get; set; } 
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public override string ToString() { return Text; } 
        }

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            int selecteVal = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue; 
            ComboboxItem selectedCar = (ComboboxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Index: [{0}] CarName={1}; Value={2}", selectedIndex, selectedCar.Text, selecteVal));
        }
```

I'm adding them like:

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                    item.Text = cd.Name;
                    item.Value = cd.ID;
                    this.comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

I keep getting a NullReferenceExeption and not sure why. the text seems to show up just fine.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    int selectedIndex = cmb.SelectedIndex;
    int selectedValue = (int)cmb.SelectedValue;

    ComboboxItem selectedCar = (ComboboxItem)cmb.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Index: [{0}] CarName={1}; Value={2}", selectedIndex, selectedCar.Text, selecteVal));        
}
```

Comment: I think that `ComboBoxItem` class is available only in WPF projects.

Comment: OP declared it in their post. Surprised there isn't one in the System.Windows.Forms namespace...or did I miss something?

Answer (score 15):

You are getting `NullReferenceExeption` because of you are using the `cmb.SelectedValue` which is null. the `comboBox` doesn't know what is the value of your custom class `ComboboxItem`, so either do:

```
ComboboxItem selectedCar = (ComboboxItem)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
int selecteVal = Convert.ToInt32(selectedCar.Value);
```

Or better of is use data binding like:

```
ComboboxItem item1 = new ComboboxItem();
item1.Text = "test";
item1.Value = "123";

ComboboxItem item2 = new ComboboxItem();
item2.Text = "test2";
item2.Value = "456";

List<ComboboxItem> items = new List<ComboboxItem> { item1, item2 };

this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
this.comboBox1.DataSource = items;
```

Comment: Isn't there anyway to use comboBox.SelectedValue for a custom item without using a dataSource? Eg. if you use a datasource you can't remove or add an item to the combobox Items.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar error, My Class is

```
public class ServerInfo
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string PortNo { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

But what I did, I casted my class to the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox. So, i'll have all of the class properties of the selected item.

```
// Code above
ServerInfo emailServer = (ServerInfo)cbServerName.SelectedItem;

mailClient.ServerName = emailServer.Value;
mailClient.ServerPort = emailServer.PortNo;
```

I hope this helps someone!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the selected item to your custom class (ComboboxItem)
Try this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
            int selectedIndex = cmb.SelectedIndex;
            string selectedText = this.comboBox1.Text;
            string selectedValue = ((ComboboxItem)cmb.SelectedItem).Value.ToString();

ComboboxItem selectedCar = (ComboboxItem)cmb.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Index: [{0}] CarName={1}; Value={2}", selectedIndex, selectedCar.Text, selecteVal));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void cmbLineColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)cmbLineColor.SelectedItem;
        int selectedValue = (int)drv.Row.ItemArray[1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have with the `SelectedValue` is not converting into integer. This is the main problem so usinge the following code snippet will help you:

```
int selectedValue;
bool parseOK = Int32.TryParse(cmb.SelectedValue.ToString(), out selectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
int selectedValue = (int)comboBox1.Items[selectedIndex];
```

Comment: OP had a C# question. Your answer looks like C++.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to cast combobox value to a custom type,
if you do like this the code is still IntelliSense(code suggestion is enable)

### When you want to set values

```cs
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ComboValue";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ComboName";

    comboBox1.Items.Add(new
    {
        ComboValue= myCustomTypeInstanse,
        ComboName = myCustomType.Blah.Blah
    });
```

### When you want to get back value of a custom type(your own class)

```cs
    var item = (dynamic)comboBox1.SelectedItem; // anonymous to dynamic
    var myCustomType= (CustomType)item.ComboValue; // <-- type casting
    MessageBox.Show(myCustomType.Blah.Blah);
```