# Retrieve Value/Name of selected item of comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm working on a winforms application, I have a comboBox that I bind from a database, each item have a Name and a Value:

```
 // New item class
 public class themeS
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }
     public override string ToString() { return this.Name; }
 }

 // Binding ComboBox Event
 using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
 {
    comboBox2.Items.Clear();
    IEnumerable tem  = from t in db.Themes where t.idCategorie == 1  select t;
    foreach (Themes Tem in tem)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(new themeS { Value = Tem.idTheme.ToString(), Name= Tem.nomTheme });
    }
 }
```

Now I want to retrieve the Value of selected item of combobox:

```
string curentIdTem = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

The returned value of `comboBox2.SelectedValue` is always 'NULL', can someone help please?

Comment: Can you check if the `SelectedValue` is an `int`

Comment: @jacobaloysious It's a `string`.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901070/getting-selected-value-of-a-combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int curentIdTem =  Convert.ToInt32(((themeS)comboBox2.SelectedItem).Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are casting a class `themeS` to an `int` which would not work.

If you are expecting an `int` value in the `Value` property in `themeS` class.

Then you could retrieve it this way: `Int32.TryParse`

```
    int currentItem = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(((themeS)comboBox2.SelectedValue).Value, out     currentItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `SelectedValue` you need to set the `ValueMember` on the `ComboBox`

Example:

```
   comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
   .....

   int value = (int)comboBox2.SelectedValue;
```