# ComboBox items using loop

Tags: c#, loops, drop-down-menu, combobox

currently i have combobox in my win forms application and, just for test i made a loop so it adds 10 items, but all 10 items in combobox are same!

here is my loop in main class: `

```
       void AddValue(){
             ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            item.Text = "Item " + i;
            item.Value = i;
            ModDown.Items.Add(item);
        }
       }
```

and ComboboxItem class: `

```
    class ComboboxItem
      {

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

thanks for any help!

- Nick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep adding the same ComboBoxItem to the combobox. You just change its property consequently.

```
void AddValue()
{
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
    item.Text = "Item " + i;
    item.Value = i;
    ModDown.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: :D haha didn't notice that thanks anyways! but what about getting value of it. for eg: when i press button messagebox shows up and it should write Combobox1.SelectedValue, but i get: null

Comment: Get a look over there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901070/getting-selected-value-of-a-combobox

Comment: Thank you! you really helped me out!