# Not able to convert the value from Combo Box to Integer

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to get the value which is selected in a combo box in its handler so that I could do some operations based on every change of value. But i'm unable to convert the value into an integer. When I tried to convert it to a string and print it on the console, its printing as "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: 100000" if the selected value is 100000.

Please find the XAML and handler code below.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Scale" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="660,15,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Height="26" SelectionChanged="Scale_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="750" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="4000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="5000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="10000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="20000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="40000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="50000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="100000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60"/>
</ComboBox>
```

C# code

```
private void Scale_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Scale.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting selected value of a combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901070/getting-selected-value-of-a-combobox)

Comment: Also see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4902454](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4902454) for explanation.

Comment: WPF = bindings. Don't create `ComboBoxItem`'s yourself like this. Don't get values from View, but from underlying collection directly, then you don't need any casting. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19632600/1997232), or [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the ComboBox is filled with a bunch of `ComboBoxItem` objects, and since `SelectedValuePath` is not specified, the `SelectedValue` will also be a `<ComboBoxItem>` object.

An easy way to fix that is to set the `SelectedValuePath` to the `"Content"` property :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Scale" 
          SelectionChanged="Scale_SelectionChanged" 
          SelectedValuePath="Content" ...>
```

This way, the `SelectedValue` will point to `ComboBoxItem.Content` of the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

may be in this case SelectedItem property is populated and SelectedValue property is NULL.
so try this

```
 Console.WriteLine(Scale.SelectedItem.ToString());
```