# Windows Form showing wrong value in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the data it is connected to:

[image]

Here is the combo box set up:

[image]

What I am calling

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.ValueMember);
}
```

This shows up:

[image]

But the combo description works fine:

[image]

Why is the messagebox not showing 1 or 2?

Comment: Have you tried `SelectedValue`, since you are evidently binding *or* `SelectedItem` *if NOT binding*? I can't see pictures here on my end either, it's best if they contain errors and what not, to post them in your post... IMHO, [**have**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/combobox-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedwhat) a read there about this.

Comment: `ValueMember` = the member you have Bound your Combobox to, but not the current value it is, have a look at your second Image, what did you write in "Value Member"? and thats what you are getting with your code

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue);` should give you the results you are looking for. When in doubt, set a breakpoint on the `button1_Click` method and inspect the state of your `comboBox1` object. More than likely, the data you want is there, but you're referencing the wrong field.

Comment: Hi all.. no it says `cannot convert from object to string`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901070/getting-selected-value-of-a-combobox just a thought, this has been answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectedValue` property which gets the value of `ValueMember` property which in your case is `privilege`

> Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the
>   ValueMember property.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Hi, error says: Cannot convert from object to string

Comment: @98Ed add `comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()` Also why not give any feedback to comments asking for clarification?